# Bug displaying characters of Segoe MDL2 Assets after converting them to string

Tags: xaml, data-binding, icons, font-awesome

I'm using xaml universal project and have problem displaying some characters of font Segoe MDL2 Assets after converting to string in code behind. Please see images and anyone with ideia how to fix this:

[image: icons from font Segoe MDL2 Assets]

Xaml:

```
<converters:MyTypeConv x:Key="myTypeConv" />

<dSrc:clsLstElem x:Key="lstCmdAnsw">
        <dSrc:clsElem iAuto="0" />
        <dSrc:clsElem iAuto="1" />
        <dSrc:clsElem iAuto="2" />
</dSrc:clsLstElem>
```

Xaml usage:

```
 <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource lstCmdAnsw}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button
                 Content="{Binding iAuto, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myTypeConv}}" 
                 FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                 FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

Code behind:

```
     public class MyTypeConv : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
     {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                                  object parameter, string language)
        {
                    string s = string.Empty;
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        switch ((int)value)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                s = "\uE81D";
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                s = "\uE927;";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                s = "\uE916;;";
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    return s;
         }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your string conversion code?

Comment: the first row are all written in xaml:

Comment: Just added all code used the 1st row are buttons created in xaml using Content = "&#xEE81D;"   NOTE not all characters have this error the radio icon works fine along with others I did not illustrate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the trailing semicolons, i.e. replace

```
s = "\uE927;";
s = "\uE916;;";
```

by

```
s = "\uE927";
s = "\uE916";
```